# AVPlayerView adds brightness to videos with HDR turned on

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a video that is saved locally in the cache folder and I load it using a URL Here's the code:

I'm using  AVQueuePlayer, AVPlayerViewController, and AVPlayerLooper.

```
        internal void LoadVideoUsingURL(string url)
        {
            // / Load asset in background thread to avoid lagging
            DispatchQueue.GetGlobalQueue(DispatchQualityOfService.Background).DispatchAsync(() =>
            {
                var avasset = AVAsset.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename(url));
                avasset.LoadValuesAsynchronously(new string[] { "duration", "playable" }, () =>
                {
                    DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() =>
                    {

                        var item = new AVPlayerItem(avasset);
                        if (this.queuePlayer.CurrentItem != item)
                        {
                            this.queuePlayer.ReplaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(item);
                            this.looperPlayer = AVPlayerLooper.FromPlayer(this.queuePlayer, item);
               
  
                        }

                    });
                });
            });
        }

        private void LoadView()
        {
            try
            {
                queuePlayer.Volume =SoundON? 1.0f:0;
                playerViewController.ShowsPlaybackControls = false;
                queuePlayer.ActionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.None;
                playerViewController.VideoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.Resize;
                playerViewController.View.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
                ContentView.AddSubview(playerViewController.View);
                playerViewController.Player = queuePlayer;
                ContentView.AddSubview(BlackBackground);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public virtual void StartPlaying()
        {
         
            if (queuePlayer.CurrentItem != null && !isPlaying)
            {

                if (queuePlayer.Status == AVPlayerStatus.ReadyToPlay)
                {
                    queuePlayer.Play();
                    queuePlayer.Volume = Volume;
                    isPlaying = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.queuePlayer.CurrentItem.AddObserver(this, new NSString("status"),
NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New | NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial, StatusObservationContext.Handle);
                }

            }

        }
```

Everything is working fine except for the videos with HDR turned on having too much brightness. when I play it on QuickTime it's normal. Is there a way to disable HDR or convert HDR to SDR

[image]

Comment: Are you recording these on the iPhone/iOS with HDR tuned on?

Comment: @SushiHangover Yesss, I think that can be the reason! Is there a way to disable the HDR when I play the video same as Quicktime?

Comment: I get the same over brightness when playing HDR videos with AVPlayer (and the display dims sometimes to try to balance it and then the rest of the app is artificially dark...). This is also a problem for user's in other contexts: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/445863/hdr-playback-on-ios-social-media-apps. There is a reported user side solution to turn on low power mode which disables HDR rendering, but I have yet to find a way to programmatically disable HDR on a player. AVPlayer knows if it can do HDR via AVPlayer.eligibleForHDRPlayback but I don't know how to control it.

Comment: If one digs deep enough it seems possible to override the color space or pixel format which could force HDR off, but this seems incredibly complex, leaving this breadcrumb here incase anyone else is more patient than me: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110565

Answer (score 5):

I seem to have found a way to disable HDR in previews and exports. The result is quite good.

```
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: composition)
let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition(propertiesOf: composition)
videoComposition.colorPrimaries = AVVideoColorPrimaries_SMPTE_C
videoComposition.colorTransferFunction = AVVideoTransferFunction_SMPTE_ST_2084_PQ
videoComposition.colorYCbCrMatrix = AVVideoYCbCrMatrix_ITU_R_601_4
playerItem.videoComposition = videoComposition
```